# Primitive subgroups of the general linear group over a finite field

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields, general-linear-group

Let $q$ be a prime power and $d$ be a positive integer. Which are the primitive transitive subgroups of the general linear group $GL_d(F_q)$?
Should they contain $SL_d(F_q)$?

Comment: See [this reference](https://books.google.at/books?id=CrhmDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA101&lpg=PA101&dq=primitive+subgroups+of+GL(n,q)&source=bl&ots=9R1tndjE3V&sig=ACfU3U0ona0nR4HMdJ6I4qbf1Sh_ncSXug&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8_L7KyYXjAhUspIsKHavhD6UQ6AEwBXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=primitive%20subgroups%20of%20GL(n%2Cq)&f=false).

Comment: But this describes primitive subgroups generated by some special sets. Can I always reduce to one of those cases?